# writing hex files for linux (without a compiler/interpreter)

Tags: hex, debian, binaryfiles

I would like to learn how to write(by this I mean, handcraft a program(as opposed to using a compiler), not how to edit a hex/binary file) binary files for debian.

I've tried googling, but that hasn't been very helpful. Could someone point me in the direction of the proper reading materials. I would like to learn how to write headers and such. I'm hoping to write something for a unix-y OS (right now, my setup has debian running on a MIPS32 architecture, but learning stuff to execute on bare metal would be ok for now too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should probably read this then.

http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) for reading and [hexedit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit) for writing.

Comment: Could you provide some links?

Comment: You're welcome: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm, http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit

Comment: Hmm, I meant more along the lines of where can I learn to write headers and so forth, whether I need to align my code, what does malloc look like in assembled code, etc. Let me edit the question.